# CSV file generated from dataweave 2.0 have an empty line at the end. How to remove the empty line

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

My payload is

```json
[
  {
    "type": "Code",
    "method": "more",
    "Service": "Post",
    "Service_ID": "1"
  },
  {
     "type": "Code",
    "method": "more",
    "Service": "Put",
    "Service_ID": "2"
  },
  {
      "type": "Code",
    "method": "more",
    "Service": "get",
    "Service_ID": "3"
  }
]
```

DataWeave code to transform it to CSV with datastream:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=true, separator = "|", deferred=true
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    TYPE: payload01."type",
    METHOD: payload01."method",
    SERVICE_ID: payload01."Service_ID",
    SERVICE: payload01."Service"
}
```

Actual output:
[Actual output with empty line 5 at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmVc.png)

Expected output:
[expected output without the line 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeNnf.png)

Any help in this will be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In DataWeave the CSV each output line ends with the lineSeparator string defined in the [CSV writer properties](http://Please%20use%20text%20instead%20of%20images.%20See%20https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question%20for%20more%20details%20on%20the%20reason.) which is added to the end of each record. The default is the new line for the system. What you see is not exactly an empty line but that the previous last line ends with an end of line. If you change the lineSeparator to something different like "X" you would get this output in a single line:

```
TYPE|METHOD|SERVICE_ID|SERVICEXCode|more|1|PostXCode|more|2|PutXCode|more|3|getX
```

I'm not sure why it should be a problem. If you are not having an issue with that last new line just ignore it.

I don't recommend to do this but you could treat the CSV output as a String and remove the last sequence of new line but be careful could be more than one character depending on the configuration of the operating system. It is not practical for big payloads to operate on big strings like that in memory and you may run out of memory.